# RecordList method not working

Tags: smartgwt

I have to reorder the **Listgrid** records.
I am using the following code, but every time it throws an exception at the following line of code:

```
rs.removeAt(idx);
```

Exception :: --

```
self.removeAt(pos) is not a function
```

Here is the code:

```
TransferImgButton upFirst = new TransferImgButton(TransferImgButton.UP_FIRST);  
upFirst.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {  
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {  
       ListGridRecord selectedRecord = myList2.getSelectedRecord();  
       if(selectedRecord != null) {  
          int idx = myList2.getRecordIndex(selectedRecord);  
          if(idx > 0) {  
             RecordList rs = myList2.getRecordList();  
             rs.removeAt(idx);  
             rs.addAt(selectedRecord, 0);  
          }  
       }
    }  
});
```

Comment: Are you using **DataSource** for your **ListGrid**?

Comment: yes i am using datasource for my listgrid .Except this all the code is working fine .

Comment: I am not saying for particular my answer. It was for overall.

Comment: @HardikMishra : ok i will consider it ,but still if i m not satisfied with the answer i will not accept .If it helps me to resolve the problem then defiantly i will accept .

Answer (score 1):

@dhruva, If you're using **DataSource** for the **ListGrid**, then you should use that **DataSource** to add or remove data from the **ListGrid**. Personally, I don't prefer adding or removing data from **RecordList** unless some specific condition or circumstances are there. You can try the following:

```
grid.getDataSource().addData(record);
grid.getDataSource().removeData(record);
```

OR

```
grid.addData(record);
grid.removeData(record);
```

Comment: I have get all the record in record array and then reorder the records and reset into the Listgrid .in this way i reorder the listgrid data .

Comment: @Dhruva, you can reorder the List of Objects first & then make Records using them. Even if you need to reorder the grid's records dynamically, this approach works fine.

Comment: RAS :I Have applied a simple logic in which i swap the record with the target record . so the complexity is less and generic too .Thanks for ur quick replies ...

Comment: @Dhruva, Do you mean up-down records multiple or single time?

Comment: RAS: up down records on a single time .

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like stale resources.So, I would suggest you to run a GWT compile and clear your browser cache before testing.

Which SmartGwt version are you using ?

Use nightly builds or 2.4
Here is the [link](http://www.smartclient.com/builds/SmartGWT/2.x/LGPL/2011-08-08).

Comment: I have cleaned the browser cache and run a GWT compile too . but the problem is not belong to this .There is a bug in that method and it is not working properly(i am using 2.4 version of smartGWT) . I myself founds the other option to do that.